# Spring cloud client configuration for multiple module project

Tags: java, spring-cloud

Though I have successfully setup spring cloud config client/server with GIT as backend properties repo. However I have a basic question for following module structure (maven) for one of my client code:

Client 1:

```
  common (maven module)
  app (maven module)
  web (Contains the spring boot application, bootstrap.properties, application.properties)
```

For the above structure, I am able to read/refresh properties from spring cloud config server for the "web" module (since that is the one where my SpringBootApplication is), however not able to understand that how to inject configure/inject properties in other modules as well, like there could be properties for common module or app module.

I tried adding bootstrap.properties in other modules with them pointing to same spring cloud config server. But that did not work out.

**Spring cloud config server application.properties:**

server.port=8888

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=

management.security.enabled=false

**web module's bootstrap.properties**

spring.application.name=test

spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888

management.security.enabled=false

spring.profiles.active=default,prod

**Maven dependencies (cloud config client):**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please help me to understand, as to how I can read/refresh the properties across multiple modules like common, app or web which would be deployed on single instance/client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `common` and `app` modules aren't applications, they won't start and thus won't read your bootstrap.properties files.

Take a look at [type-safe configuration properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) and [third party configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-3rd-party-configuration).

Your `common` and `app` modules can provide multiple classes with their properties.
In the Java configuration of your `web` module you can set up the binding between the values in your `bootstrap.properties` and/or `application.properties` files, and the configuration classes.
Because of the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation, Spring Boot will create regular beans of these configuration classes. That way you can inject your configuration just like any other bean.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Could you please let me know how the binding works between spring.application.name=test & @ConfigurationProperties? Is it through the prefix?

Comment: @TYsewn For now what I have done is added prefix "test" to all property keys in different profile files in GIT like test.properties and test-prod.properties like and created a @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test") and it worked for me. But not sure if this is the best way to achieve it.

Comment: So if you put `spring.application.name=name` in your `application.properties` file, you can get that value either by using `@Value("${spring.application.name}")` or by creating a class (eg. `ApplicationProperties`) with a property `name`. If you annotate that class or your bean with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.application")`, it will retrieve the value from the file and store it in the `name` property of the `ApplicationProperties` class. You don't need to change the name of the `.properties` files in order for it to work.

Comment: Thanks @TYsewyn! I added the prefix to the files so as to pick only the files with scope "spring.application.name=test" defined in bootstrap.properties as that is what I got to understand from spring cloud docs. Also had added different profiles like default, prod to pick multiple property files that were prefixed with "test" & "test-prod". The second part was to pick property keys with prefix in @ConfigurationProperties(prefix ="test") and I added prefix to keys in property files like "test.id", "test.url" or "test.interval" etc. Now able to use this Property class across all the modules.